# How the kernel continues with the three way handshake after it sets the state to TCP_SYN_RECV

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand how the TCP three way handshake is implemented in Linux kernel, version 2.6.33.

I started with function accept() which leads me to:

accept()==>sys_accept()==>sys_accept4()==>inet_accept()==>inet_csk_accept()

Now I am stucked in inet_csk_accept().

```
struct sock *inet_csk_accept(struct sock *sk, int flags, int *err)
 {
     struct inet_connection_sock *icsk = inet_csk(sk);
     struct sock *newsk;
     int error;

     lock_sock(sk);

     /* We need to make sure that this socket is listening,
      * and that it has something pending.
      */
     error = -EINVAL;
     if (sk->sk_state != TCP_LISTEN)
             goto out_err;

     /* Find already established connection */
     if (reqsk_queue_empty(&icsk->icsk_accept_queue)) {
             long timeo = sock_rcvtimeo(sk, flags & O_NONBLOCK);

             /* If this is a non blocking socket don't sleep */
             error = -EAGAIN;
             if (!timeo)
                     goto out_err;

             error = inet_csk_wait_for_connect(sk, timeo);
             if (error)
                     goto out_err;
     }

     newsk = reqsk_queue_get_child(&icsk->icsk_accept_queue, sk);
     WARN_ON(newsk->sk_state == TCP_SYN_RECV);
 out:
     release_sock(sk);
     return newsk;
 out_err:
     newsk = NULL;
     *err = error;
     goto out;
 }
```

My question is when the programs goes to

```
WARN_ON(newsk->sk_state == TCP_SYN_RECV);
```

1. the three way handshake already finished?
2. Where is the code that the server sends the ACK?
3. Where is the code that the server confirms the ACK from client?
4. or if I was wrong at the beginning, is the three way handshake is implemented all inside accpet()?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual socket logic for TCP located in

```
net/ipv4/tcp_input.c
```

State machine for socket is located in function

```
int tcp_rcv_state_process(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb,
              struct tcphdr *th, unsigned len)
```

which implement all socket state transitions (including three way handshake).
This function is called this way:

```
tcp_v4_rcv => tcp_v4_do_rcv => tcp_rcv_state_process
```

for every received TCP packet. This call is initiated by interface driver (i.e. driver for network adapter).

`accept()` only waits for socket state to be changed from `TCP_LISTEN` to `TCP_ESTABLISHED`. And state TCP_LISTEN is set by `listen()`. Actual state change is performed in `tcp_rcv_state_process`.

So this process is asynchronous. Call to `accept()` does not directly lead to call to `tcp_rcv_state_process`

Comment: Hi @werewindle, thanks for your answer. I've looked at the tcp_rcv_state_process function. And I still have the question that in a simple TCP server with bind(), listen(),accept(), send(), which function lead the kernel to tcp_rcv_state_process? thanks

Comment: @sliter. I extended my answer to describe who calls which function. On short - tcp_rcv_state_process called when new packet arrives. And it called by interface, from which this packed arrived.

Comment: Hello @werewindle, do you know where the kernel sends out the first SYN pkt as client? I cannot find it in `tcp_rcv_state_process()`

Comment: @zzy Take a look at tcp_connect() function in tcp_output.c (it is called by tcp_v4_connect())

Answer (score 0):

Many functions is involved in the state transition.   But in general, there is one general function that just change the state:   tcp_set_state().

Doing a grep in net/ipv4/*.c sources:

```html
tcp.c:  tcp_set_state(sk, ns);
tcp.c:      tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp.c:      tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp.c:          tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp.c:          tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp.c:      tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp.c:  tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
tcp_input.c:        tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE_WAIT);
tcp_input.c:        tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSING);
tcp_input.c:    tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_ESTABLISHED);
tcp_input.c:        tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_SYN_RECV);
tcp_input.c:        tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_ESTABLISHED);
tcp_input.c:        tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_FIN_WAIT2);
tcp_ipv4.c: tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_SYN_SENT);
tcp_ipv4.c: tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
```

and now randomly picked one of them:

tcp.c: tcp_fin(), which handle the FIN state transition:

```
static void tcp_fin(struct sock *sk)
{
        struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
        const struct dst_entry *dst;

        inet_csk_schedule_ack(sk);

        sk->sk_shutdown |= RCV_SHUTDOWN;
        sock_set_flag(sk, SOCK_DONE);

        switch (sk->sk_state) {
        case TCP_SYN_RECV:
        case TCP_ESTABLISHED:
                /* Move to CLOSE_WAIT */
                tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE_WAIT);
```

So you can see from above the before (ie, TCP_SYN_RECV) and after state changed by the tcp_set_state() function.

In another function (also tcp_input.c):

```
static int tcp_rcv_synsent_state_process()
```

Here is the setting to TCP_SYN_RECV via calling tcp_set_state(), and then it continues with other processing as well.

Either one of the above scenario covers the state processing after the TCP_SYN_RECV state.